# Remove Item in datagridcombocell when its already use on another row C#

Tags: c#

Hello i want to remove a item from datagridcombocell which is use on another row in same cell like this

when i select qw2120 so on next row it will not display the same item on combo cell

how its possible?

Comment: It will help others answer your question if you include some example code that shows what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
    lstCombo.Clear();
                           foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                           {
                               lstCombo.Add(dr.Field<string>("ProductCode").ToString());


                           }
                           foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                           {
                               if (e.RowIndex == 0)
                                   ProductCode.Items.Add(dr.Field<string>("ProductCode").ToString());
                               else
                               {
                                   ProductCode.Items.Clear();
                                   int i = 0;
                                   foreach (var item in lstCombo)
                                   {
                                       if (item.ToString() == dgDetail.Rows[e.RowIndex - 1].Cells["ProductCode"].Value.ToString())
                                       { lstCombo.RemoveAt(i); break; }
                                       else i++;
                                   }
                                   foreach (var items in lstCombo) ;
                                   // ProductCode.
                               }
                           }
```

This is my code Denise